# Selecting text value from next span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that dynamically generates input fields based on an ajax response. What I am trying to do is multiply the tet value of the first span by a user input, and display the results in the third. I have the functionality working correctly in an html table structure, but can't get it working for the span.

Here is the link for my working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/zj5bca4g/1/

And here is the one I am having issues with, I am trying to keep the same structure. https://jsfiddle.net/fg5ygrke/

```
<span class="cost" name="cost[]"   value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]" >0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]"   value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]" >0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]"   value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]" >0</span>
```

And the JS.

```
$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).next('span');
  var cost = parseFloat($tr.find('.cost').text()) || 0;
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
  $tr.find('.total').text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the

> .next()

and

> .prev()

function of JQuery

something like this

```
$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).next('span');
  var cost = parseFloat($(this).prev('.cost').text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
  $($tr).text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);
})
```

here is a jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fg5ygrke/2/

Comment: This works, thanks. But what if I had each <span> inside of a div, such as <div><span>total</span></div>. Would I be able to use the same approach to find the next span?

Comment: you can use .next().find('.total') or .prev().find('.cost')

Answer (score 0):

Spans don't have a value attribute and `.find()` searches descendant elements. You want `.next()` and `.prev()`

```js
$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var cost = $(this).prev('.cost').text();
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
  $(this).next('.total').text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cost" name="cost[]">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]" >5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
```